# Excel file name, sheet name and pages

Tags: vba, excel

How can I change text `FILE NAME`, `PAGE NAME`, `PAGE OF PAGES` into an automatic code, When I use `&F` for file name I get routing and everything messed up.

It's in Excel:

```
Sub Podnozje()
'
' Podnozje Makro
'
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10Ersteller: CUTC HR"
        .CenterFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10FILE NAME" & Chr(10) & "PAGE NAME" & Chr(10) & "PAGE OF PAGES"
        .RightFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10Druckdatum: &Date"
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a fresh workbook the following code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateFooters()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "" 'sometimes I had issues without clearing the footer first

        .LeftFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10 Ersteller: CUTC HR"
        .CenterFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10 &F" & Chr(10) & "&A" & Chr(10) & "Seite &P von &N"
        .RightFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10 Druckdatum: &D"
    End With
End Sub
```

results in

[image]

---

These are the valid codes:

- `&P` - the current page number.
- `&N` - the total number of pages.
- `&B` - use a bold font*.
- `&I` - use an italic font*.
- `&U` - use an underline font*.
- `&&` - the '&' character.
- `&D` - the current date.
- `&T` - the current time.
- `&F` - workbook name.
- `&A` - worksheet name.
- `&"FontName"` - use the specified font name.
- `&N` - use the specified font size.